# The new syntax highlighter color choices are confusing

Tags: feature-request, bug, syntax-highlighting

The new syntax highlighter has confusing colors for different token types in C:

- The same reddish color is used for function names, structure tags, types and numbers. Prettify did not use to differentiate identifiers and function names from punctuation and operators. Using a different color makes them stand out as a different type of token, which is fine, but using the same color for these 4 different cases is confusing as they do not have the same semantic value.
- The same blue color is used for keywords and preprocessing directives: again a very different semantic value

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// this is a comment
/* this is a comment too */

#define TRUE 1

typedef struct str_s {
    char *str;
    size_t len;
} string;

typedef struct str_t {
    char *str;
    size_t len;
} mystring;

int main(void) {
    char dest[10];
    printf("Hello world\n");
    strcpy(dest, "ABC");
    string s;
    s.str = dest;
    s.len = strlen(s.str);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code snippet, I don't even understand why `string` is colored in red whereas `mystring` is not.

Can we have the previous theme colors?

Can the theme colors depend on the language tag?

Can we customize the theme colors?

Comment: ***This*** is *`how`* _this_ **color** `scheme` `i`s *making* ***me*** **fe**_e**l**_.͕̝̺̘̾̽ͤ͢͟͡

Comment: Functions aren't blue, and now I want to say boo.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the code is parsed into categories, and there's noway to change that unless you change the syntax highlighting source. This isn't about the colours applied to the categories. "string" has been categorized a "hljs-built_in" where as "mystring" hasn't even qualified to be in any category as can be seen by [inspecting the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwMyg.png)

Comment: I haven't noticed anything strange for Java yet, but I don't think the new highlighting is ideal. The previous highlighting was very neutral and simplistic, which is good. The new one depends on the viewer's taste, which is not good.

Comment: I did a customization by using Stylus browser extension which is used to insert user css styles on any site/url. There aren't a lot of style rules involved. Approximately  10.  You can get the `default.css` code from highlightjs github repo, paste it in Stylus editor, add `!important` to all the rules in just a few minutes. Then use the built in color picker in the Stylus stylesheet editor  to see real time changes on a page such as this one or on SO proper. Even if the dev team does offer up different themes it's still nice to have your own tweaked to personal taste

Comment: @charlietfl: hacking one's own browser rendering is doable, although I would prefer a simpler plugin than the huge *stylus* package, but it does not help casual readers of SO, especially newbies that these questionable theme colors will likely confuse.

Comment: @Scratte: indeed I noticed this `hljs-built_in` style: `string` is **not** a C built-in anything.

Comment: Agree it is not the optimal solution and dev team should probably to some customization themselves to revert to same defaults as prior highlighter used. Horrible having to all of a sudden deal with a new theme forced on us. I hated it enough to want the quick fix approach

Comment: The color pair brownish orange / olive green is a **disaster** for red-green color blind people.

Comment: @Mico: this makes the new theme even worse than I imagined: red-green [color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness), aka Daltonism, is estimated to affect around 8% of men to some degree. Furthermore given the current Covid pandemic, it seems to be a known side effect of [Chloroquine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroquine_retinopathy) treatments.

Comment: I believe this problem should be discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter)

Comment: Circus colors for programming has always been ridiculous to the point where it's only a blur and gives no meaning. The only reason people now want color highlights is cause they read somewhere you're supposed to have color highlights but no other reason.

Comment: @chqrlie if you look into the highlight source code, the reason for the bad colourings are because "C === C++", **and** they've got this misguided attempt at colouring C++ declarations differently from statements.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala:  This change of highlighter is a significant downgrade for the C language. I wonder what prompted the change: lack of support for some new languages? which ones? the solution is to improve highlight.js at the source but this will not suffice if different styles are merged back into the same color in the theme that cannot be customised on a language basis.

Comment: @chqrlie https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354753/190417

Comment: I was puzzled why strings are green and comments gray. The other way round is more common imho.

Comment: @marsze I think that's totally fine, and not that uncommon (Github for example). Comments being gray was the old style as well.

Comment: @chqrlie [Maintainer of Highlight.js here] We have a single grammar for C and C++ so that's why `string` is a built_in - and yes, it's suboptimal.  This super recently changed, and now we have both C and C++ grammars, though I'm not sure if SE will choose to bundle both.  We could use some contributors to help slim down the C subset though as right now they are separate but still pretty much clones of each other.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala *and they've got this misguided attempt at colouring C++ declarations differently from statements* ... If you open a bug report I'd be happy to learn more about this and whether it's something we could fix...

Comment: @JoshGoebel well, it is getting fixed slowly, seems that C and C++ were separated from the "c-like"... I am not saying that colouring declarations differently from statements is wrong if you *can do it right*, it is just that it is **impossible** to do right without complete source and a C++ compiler. `x * y(z);` is undecidable alone - is that a declaration or an expression?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I just ripped them apart the other day so they would finally diverge.  `y(z)` would now be considered a function dispatch (same way VS Code highlighting perceives it) and be highlighted as `built_in` (for now) per work in progress: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/3005

Comment: @JoshGoebel: I am certainly interested in contributing to Highlight.js, I shall contact you shortly.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with @Braiam that there are certainly things that can be improved upstream, one issue that can be addressed on Stack's-side (or our client-side) is how Stack *styles* the code tokens that HLJS spits out. In Stack's current site CSS, there are 9 token types that are mapped to the orange color visible above, *4* of which are used in your block above.

Having a lot of duplicate colors likely doesn't cause problems if a given code block doesn't contain tons of these like-colored tokens strung together, but in your C example above, it really impacts readability a lot, especially in the final stanza... and this snippet doesn't use weird syntax, it's a few lines of *very* common and basic C code.

This situation could be improved, at least to *some* extent, simply by **reallocating the existing tokens to better color selections**. For my experiment, I reallocated `.hljs-number` (exactly what it sounds like) from blue to purple, and then `.hljs-type` (in C, this appears to be most type names of variables) from orange to blue.

Results are below, with VS Code's Light+ theme included for comparison:

| Original | With Class Tweak | VS Code Light+ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Image of code block above, no style change] | [image: Image of code block above, with style modification to make types and numbers a different color] | [image: Image of code block above, but in VS Code with the Light+ theme selected] |

While this doesn't bring about miracles, and I don't want to oversell the recoloring of a couple tokens as *the* solution, I do still think there's *some* improvement to be had here, and it does bring the highlighting closer to something like VS Code. I don't think the changes need to be drastic to get useful results.

I wrote up [a userscript](https://github.com/zcoop98/Userscripts/blob/master/StackExchange/SE_HLJS-ClassTweaks.user.js) with these two class changes if you want to take them for a spin yourself.

---

Here's the full color list, for reference (yes, there are indeed two pairs of duplicate variables):

| Color Variable | Light Theme Color | Dark Theme Color | Color Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --highlight-color | [image] #2f3337 | [image] #fff | More or less default text color (Near Black/ White) |
| --highlight-comment | [image] #656e77 | [image] #999 | Grey |
| --highlight-symbol | [image] #803378 | [image] #c59bc1 | Magenta |
| --highlight-keyword | [image] #015692 | [image] #88aece | Blue |
| --highlight-attribute | [image] #015692 | [image] #88aece | Blue |
| --highlight-namespace | [image] #b75501 | [image] #f08d49 | Orange |
| --highlight-literal | [image] #b75501 | [image] #f08d49 | Orange |
| --highlight-variable | [image] #54790d | [image] #b5bd68 | Yellowish-Green |
| --highlight-punctuation | [image] #535a60 | [image] #ccc | Lighter Grey |
| --highlight-deletion | [image] #c02d2e | [image] #de7176 | Red |
| --highlight-addition | [image] #2f6f44 | [image] #76c490 | Green |

Answer (score 0):

> In the above code snippet, I don't even understand why string is colored in red whereas mystring is not.

Because string is "built_in" while mystring is just text:

```
<span class="hljs-keyword">typedef</span> <span class="hljs-class"><span class="hljs-keyword">struct</span> <span class="hljs-title">str_s</span> {</span>
    <span class="hljs-keyword">char</span> *str;
    <span class="hljs-keyword">size_t</span> len;
} <span class="hljs-built_in">string</span>;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ highlight class

<span class="hljs-keyword">typedef</span> <span class="hljs-class"><span class="hljs-keyword">struct</span> <span class="hljs-title">str_t</span> {</span>
    <span class="hljs-keyword">char</span> *str;
    <span class="hljs-keyword">size_t</span> len;
} mystring;
  ^^^^^^^^ no class :(
```

> Can we have the previous theme colors?

It won't help.

> Can the theme colors depend on the language tag?

Nope, it depends on what language is declared and how that maps to colors.

> Can we customize the theme colors?

The highlighter does have themes, but it won't help.

The fix would be that context should be preferred over "built_in", and that fix must come [from upstream](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/c-like.js#L129).

Comment: *"Because string is "built_in" while mystring is just text:"*, except that there is nothing in C with `string` in it, besides `string` inside `<string.h>`, `"string.h"` that would be handled by other syntax rules anyway.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that's what the creator of the highlighter implemented. [Whenever you find "string" mark it as built-in.](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/5b87cc4d106059bee1c30f123e5a4053e0af9de4/src/languages/c-like.js#L109)

Comment: Holy moly that's so dumb... it's parsing C with random C++ keywords. Wow.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Well, pull requests are accepted by upstream to make it less dumb :D https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/

Comment: Not really worth my time, that's only the tip of the iceberg of problems with the new highliter. Should have stuck to Prettify to be honest.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli well, Prettify was a dead end project and I doubt SE would have invested resources into it. At least, this one we can improve.

Comment: I'll take unmaintained but working over maintained but nonsensical and broken any day.