# Add CSS rules for syntax highlighting of operators

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The current syntax highlight is somewhat minimal, because the engine (unlike some others) intentionally doesn’t highlight identifiers at all (unless they have a special meaning<sup>1</sup>).

In principle that’s fine. However, it often means that *no* (or almost no) highlighting is applied to a piece of code. The result is uniformly black, and no structural information is given. This defeats the whole point of syntax highlighting. Here’s an (extreme, but not atypical) example using R:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

result = df %>%  mutate(`Total (%)` = Total / sum_na(Total))
```

Here’s how this is rendered for me:

[image: no syntax highlighting]

… and here’s how it *could* be rendered:

[image: with operator/punctuation syntax highlighting]

It’s not a massive difference, but it distinguishes structural tokens and improves readability. **highlight.js already generates the required markup (for some languages), Stack Overflow just needs to add suitable CSS.**

---

<sup>1</sup> Other users have already remarked that [the chosen colours lead to confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401553/1968), because function definitions for example are highlighted identically to keywords, builtins, and (non-string) literals. This isn’t inherent in the syntax highlight engine, it’s a design choice.

Comment: The highlighting seems *more* confusing to me, given that nothing else is highlighted. Do IDEs like Visual Studio provide syntax highlighting for operators in R?

Comment: @TylerH I have no idea what VS does but some other IDEs do. In the end it doesn’t terribly matter *what* gets highlighted as long as (some) different token types get different colours, and this is what highlight.js gives us. I have to admit that I don’t understand how this would get “more confusing”.

Comment: It highlights the operators only, which means "these are special", but they are not; they are just operators. That is why it is more confusing.

Comment: @TylerH No, it highlights *everything except regular identifiers*. My example happens to only highlight operators, because I chose it to show how little is highlighted at the moment. But other pieces of code obviously use other tokens, which are also highlighted.

Comment: I would think that library() is a special token, but that's just me being polluted by old fashioned languages :)

Comment: @Gimby There’s definitely different opinions on that but as far as R is concerned, `library` is a regular function, there’s absolutely nothing special to it. The highlight.js language definition *does* treat primitive functions as special tokens, but `library` isn’t primitive. R also has virtually no keywords (< 10!).

Comment: @KonradRudolph there you go. Given that R is -very- different from other languages, that would maybe also imply that syntax highlighting for it might work differently from other languages. Given the generic nature of this request, it might be hard for it to gain any traction.

Comment: @Gimby Oh but the same issue is totally present for other languages as well. My reason for giving an R example is that I mostly answer R questions these days and that’s the example I had at hand (extracted from an actual question). The fundamental issue is that Stack Overflow fails to apply distinct styles to many of the token types provided by the highlighter engine, and no style at all to operators. Since operators are *somewhat* new in highlight.js, I singled them out in this particular feature request. The request is intentionally generic, since the problem is general.